# Mapping PDB ID + chain ID to UniProt ID

Tags: pdb, uniprot

This question was addressed [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/how-to-map-pdb-chains-to-uniprot-ids-using-api-services).

Unfortunately, including `bioservices`, the solutions `pypdb` and `map_pdb_to_uniprot` do not work for now.

Besides, I do not need residue level mapping as one of [the suggested solution](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2719/14169).

Does the failure of known methods have anything to deal with the [recent update](https://twitter.com/uniprot/status/1541797066120302597?s=20&t=3j0E6JfW9szPtLJgX96Mlw) of the UniProt database?

Please let me know if you know a workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/docs/sifts/quick.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution here:
https://www.biostars.org/p/9540519/#9540826